Docker serve react app with nginx not working
Here is my situation. I have a working Laravel application running in docker with its front end in angular js embedded in Laravel itself. Now I am developing new front end for the application that is in React in a separate repo. On my local dev these are running in docker env. Here is my docker-compose:
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      args:
        user: ${USER}
        uid: ${UID}
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/
    environment:
      - COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phirater:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./storage/logs:/var/www/storage/logs
    networks:
      phios:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.61
    nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:80
    depends_on:
      - db
      - app
      - phirater-frontend
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./docker-compose/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl/
      - ./docker-compose/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      phios:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.63
     phirater-frontend:
    container_name: phirater-frontend
    build:
      context: ./../phirater-frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./../phirater-frontend:/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - phios

Here is my Dockerfile for pirater-frontend:
FROM node:16-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

What I am trying to do is that the main 'app' should be served on 192.168.10.63 which it does and what I want is that when I do 192.168.10.63/react it should be serve the react application. Here is my nginx config:
location /react {
    proxy_pass http://phirater-frontend:80;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    rewrite ^/react(/.*)$ $1 break;
}

This is my nginx conf for the React app:
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

Here is my dir structure:
── phios
│   ├── phirater
│   │   ├── app
│   │   ├── artisan
│   │   ├── bootstrap
│   │   ├── bower.json
│   │   ├── composer.json
│   │   ├── composer.lock
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├── database
│   │   ├── docker-compose
│   │   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── DockerfileQueueWorker
│   │   ├── entrypoint-queue-worker.sh
│   │   ├── entrypoint.sh
│   │   ├── gulpfile.js
│   │   ├── _ide_helper.php
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── package-lock.json
│   │   ├── phirater-frontend
│   │   ├── phpunit
│   │   ├── phpunit.xml
│   │   ├── phpunit.xml.bak
│   │   ├── public
│   │   ├── readme.md
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   ├── routes
│   │   ├── server.php
│   │   ├── storage
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   ├── tools
│   │   ├── vendor
│   │   └── webpack.mix.js
│   ├── phirater-frontend
│   │   ├── build
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── nginx
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── package-lock.json
│   │   ├── public
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   └── src

So currently, 192.168.10.63/react does serve react app but I have one issue:
When I make any changes to react app it doesn't hot reload, I have to build the image again for it to take effect.
Here is my App.js:
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home/Home'
import Test from './components/Home/Test'
function App() {
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <Router basename='/react'>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/test" exact element={<Test />} />
                    <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

What is the best approach to achieve something like this that the main app runs on 192.168.10.63 and the react app runs in 192.168.10.63/react?



There seems to be no explicitly defined route for /react/test in your nginx.conf


That is expected behavior, if you want a "hot reload" with docker for development purposes, instead of copying /build content to your container (as it is instructed by your Dockerfile) you may run your container with bind mount of directory where your dev build sits.



@YevhenHorbunkov and how may I do that? Could you provide some details please?

I'd recommend against overwriting the image code with a bind mount.  You can docker-compose up -d app to start the backend container, and then use a normal non-Docker Node environment to develop the frontend.  You'll then get consistent results if you go to deploy this for real, and you'll avoid various problems around file sync into containers that seem to get reported frequently.
